# More bits the merrier

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, computer-puzzle

The computer department at Puzzled State University devised an inefficient
[bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)-based
(zeros and ones) number system, `n'`,
for their ever more bit-happy machines.

Here are `n' = n` for `0 ≤ n ≤ 42`,
skipping to `X' = X` where `100000000' = X+1`,
to be solved for `X'` and `X`.

```
    n' = n             n' = n               n' = n                n' = n

    0'   0         10000'   12  b5     100000'   24  b6     1000000'   36  b7
    1'   1  b1     10001'   13         100001'   25         1000001'   37
   10'   2  b2     10010'   14         100010'   26         1000010'   38
   11'   3         10011'   15         100011'   27         1000011'   39
  100'   4  b3     10100'   16         100100'   28         1000100'   40
  101'   5         10101'   17         100101'   29         1000101'   41
 1000'   6  b4     11000'   18         101000'   30        10000000'   42  b8
 1001'   7         11001'   19         101001'   31                  .
 1010'   8         11010'   20         101010'   32                  .
 1011'   9         11011'   21         101011'   33                  .
 1100'   10        11100'   22         101100'   34               X'   X
 1101'   11        11101'   23         101101'   35       100000000'   X+1  b9
                                                                     .
                                                                     .
  bit numbers  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6  b7  b8  b9                    .
  bit values    1   2   4   6  12  24  36  42  X+1
```

Each `n' = n` is unique.
Only `1000' = 6` suits `n' = 6`, for example,
even though one could imagine
`110' = 100'+10' = 4+2 = 6` as well.
Yet `110'` does not exist in this system.

*What are the values of*  `X'` *and* `X`*?*

*What is the formulaic consistency of this number system?*

Answer (score 2):

**Not-perfectly-satisfactory answer**

First of all, it seems that

> in this system as in ordinary binary notation each bit has a definite value and the value of a given string of bits is the sum of the values associated with its 1-bits. What's different is that (1) the bit-values increase more slowly than for regular binary and (2) we therefore use only some subset of the possible bit-patterns. (Or, equivalently, (2) we only use some subset of the possible bit-patterns and therefore (1) the bit-values increase more slowly.)

Further,

> the restriction on the bit-patterns so far always takes the following form: certain pairs of bits are not permitted both to be 1. Specifically, using the numbering scheme in the puzzle starting with bit 1 on the right: bits 2 and 3 must not both be 1; bits 5 and 6 must not both be 1; bits 7 and {6, 5, or 4} must not both be 1. (But bits 6 and 4 can both be 1, so it's not that the bits are divided into cliques and only one bit from each clique can be set.)

A little more specifically,

> each bit excludes some (possibly zero) number of other bits to its right.

So in effect we are being asked

> to continue the sequence that begins 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3. Of course there are many many possible continuations, and so far I don't see anything that makes one vastly more obvious than another, which is why I find this answer less than perfectly satisfactory.

However, we can say that

> so far, the bit positions that exclude other "smaller" bit positionsare precisely the ones whose (conventional) binary representation has consecutive 1-bits. Bit positions with just one pair of consecutive 1s exclude just the next-smallest bit. Bit positions with three consecutive 1s exclude the three next-smallest bits.

So

> one possible way to continue this upward (we are now attempting to extrapolate the sequence that begins 0, 1, 3, and again this is not a problem with a unique solution) is as follows. If bit n (counting from 1 on the right) is set, look at the conventional binary representation of n and then at the string of 1-bits at its left. Consider just that string, delete its leading 1, and interpret what remains in conventional binary. *That many* bits after bit n must be zero.

If this is correct, then

> bit 8 excludes no other bits, so the valid binary strings beginning with a 1 in position 8 are just what we get by taking the strings for 0..42 and adding a 1 in position 8, so the value of bit 9 is 2x42 = 84, X is 83, and X' is 11000101.

Another closely-related choice leading to the same conclusion for X,X' (but extending to infinity differently) would be

> that the number of bits below the nth excluded by bit n is obtained by ["planing"](https://oeis.org/A318921) the binary expansion of n -- deleting one from each consecutive run of equal bits.

I suspect (especially as I don't really have an answer to the question "what is the formulaic consistency of this number system?") that humn has something more specific in mind. But I don't think the information we have been given so far suffices to pin it down.

Comment: Those are the values alright, wow, @Gareth McCaughan!
The formula is surprisingly straightforward though,
in a slightly untraditional yet quite fair way,
but I tried to keep data to a screenful.
The values for 0 ≤ n ≤ 41 do have the unintended red herring
of looking like binary-coded base 6,
which is why the list goes to n = 42.
Should I somehow add clues for the next few bits?

Comment: The 3 low-order bits also have an unintended red herring
that smells like regular binary and recurs in many other bits.